# PHP text to emoticons

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been kinda struggling a little...

I looked up around 5 stackoverflow questions about this, but none of them seemed to work the way I have in mind. Basically I just want to replace "words" with emoticons.

The problem is that I want the word to be converted *only* when the word isn't a part of another word.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$text = ":D i dont kn:ow about this :O i just want to :) and :D everyday:P";
$icons = array(
        ':)' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/smile_yell.png" />',
        ':D' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/laugh_yell.png" />',
        ':(' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/sad_yell.png" />',
        '>:O' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/scared_yell.png" />',
        ':p' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/tongue_yell.png" />',
        ':P' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/tongue_yell.png" />',
        ':O' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/surprised_yell.png" />',
        ':o' => '<img class="postemot" src="/emoticons/surprised_yell.png" />'
    );
    foreach($icons as $icon=>$image) {
          $icon = preg_quote($icon);
          $text = preg_replace("~\b$icon\b~",$image,$text);
    }
    echo $text;
```

But it just didn't work. The output was not correct. Actually the only outputted emoticon was the last one, the **"everyday:P"**, which is incorrect.

Comment: The things you need to take into consideration... when is the emoticon a part of another word?? what separates the emoticon from words???

Comment: @Hallur - It's not what separates them. It's what makes them acceptable to be outputted as emoticon. For example, when the emoticon is alone, with no other letters around it, let's output it. I don't know what do you even mean to be honest...

Comment: $icon can contain opening and closing bracket; these need to be escaped in regex.

Comment: @JosefScript See `preg_quote`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: How about `~(?<!\S)$icon(?!\S)~` ?

Comment: @revo - excellent. Seem to work perfectly even when the emoticon is at the start of the string. Could you maybe explain it?

Comment: @revo - Or better, post it as an answer to get some of that juicy points :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying word boundary metacharacters around emoticons is not right since `\b` matches a position that is not desired:

```
everyday:P
        ^ asserts right before here
```

So you have to work with another assertion using lookarounds to ensure emoticon is not surrounded by a non-space character:

```
(?<!\S)$icon(?!\S)
```

Comment: Just to note, this could also be done without regex: `$text = str_replace(" $icon ", " $image ", " $text ");`